# Use Postgresql as a datasource for Microsoft Analysis Services

Tags: postgresql, ssas

Has anyone managed to use Postgresql as a datasource for SSAS? The Postgresql .NET connector seems promising, but the SSAS view wizard does not seem to be able to see the tables in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually possible to hack the Postgresql .NET connector and implement a "MSSQL compatibility mode", where the [ and ] around tables and schema names are removed. Using this, the list of tables does not appear in MS SSAS, but it is possible to replace them by views.

Comment: Could you expand on how you would do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the ODBC connector. I've had success getting other tools to connect to PG using it. The EnterpriseDB installers not only include a well packaged, working version of PG for windows, they include working, correctly installed drivers.

http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload

Comment: Unfortunately, Microsoft has stopped supporting ODBC for recent versions of SSAS, so now it must be either OleDB or .NET

Answer (score 1):

try pg_bulkload for load from via c# & from mssql to pgsql

copy & bcp (ssis) for second direction (pgsql->ssas)

242